# using WebBrowser Control in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webbrowser-control, rcw

Is it possible to create one and only WebBrowser control and keep it in Session Values and then use it when neccessary? if so, how?

I create the WebBrowser object and keep it and keep it in some Session value but whenever i try to access the object, I get "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" error.

I'm stucked.

Comment: The WebBrowser control is for Windows Forms or WPF. How and why do you want to use it an an ASP.NET application?

Comment: It's Windows Forms. I need to navigate some external website, fill up some fields, and get the html results of that website. This website requires authentication, so I can't create a webbrowser object for every request of my user.